# Styling Kendo Window's content with Bootstrap

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, kendo-ui, kendo-window

I have a generic Kendo Window that I call for different partial views. I can't style contents using bootstrap, as it causes different layouts in different browsers and elements are always cluttered.

This is a sample:

```
<div class="form-group form-inline">
    <div class="line">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.2, new { @class = "col-xs-4 control-label" })
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.2)
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.3, new { @class = "col-xs-4 control-label" })
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.3)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="line">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.4, new { @class = "col-xs-4 control-label" })
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.4)
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.5, new { @class = "col-xs-4 control-label" })
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.5)
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="clearfix">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="clearfix">&nbsp;</div>
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Class...>()
....
```

And line:

```
.line{
    line-height: 20px;
}
```

Am I missing something? I just want to have a 2-column layout. Can you give me an example please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know why, but I should use `col-xs-5`. Also, to keep elements inside a `tab strip` I have to put them inside a `container`.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="form-group form-inline col-xs-12">
        <div class="col-xs-5"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-5"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group form-inline col-xs-12">
        <div class="col-xs-5"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-5"></div>
    </div>
......
</div>
```

**UPDATE**
I found the solution at [their documents](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/using-kendo-with-twitter-bootstrap).

First you need to add the following references.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/VERSION/styles/kendo.common-bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/VERSION/styles/kendo.bootstrap.min.css">
```

And then add the following CSS to your site.css and include it in the page:

```
/* reset everything to the default box model */

*, :before, :after
{
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}

/* set a border-box model only to elements that need it */

.form-control, /* if this class is applied to a Kendo UI widget, its layout may change */
.container,
.container-fluid,
.row,
.col-xs-1, .col-sm-1, .col-md-1, .col-lg-1,
.col-xs-2, .col-sm-2, .col-md-2, .col-lg-2,
.col-xs-3, .col-sm-3, .col-md-3, .col-lg-3,
.col-xs-4, .col-sm-4, .col-md-4, .col-lg-4,
.col-xs-5, .col-sm-5, .col-md-5, .col-lg-5,
.col-xs-6, .col-sm-6, .col-md-6, .col-lg-6,
.col-xs-7, .col-sm-7, .col-md-7, .col-lg-7,
.col-xs-8, .col-sm-8, .col-md-8, .col-lg-8,
.col-xs-9, .col-sm-9, .col-md-9, .col-lg-9,
.col-xs-10, .col-sm-10, .col-md-10, .col-lg-10,
.col-xs-11, .col-sm-11, .col-md-11, .col-lg-11,
.col-xs-12, .col-sm-12, .col-md-12, .col-lg-12
{
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

And everything works fine, you should be able to use the following:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="form-group form-inline col-xs-12">
        <div class="col-xs-6"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-6"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group form-inline col-xs-12">
        <div class="col-xs-6"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-6"></div>
    </div>
......
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably need something like this. Play with the column widths depending on your labels.

```
<div class="form-group form-inline">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.2, new { @class = "control-label" })
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.2)
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group form-inline">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.3, new { @class = "control-label" })
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.3)
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group form-inline">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.4, new { @class = "control-label" })
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.4)
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group form-inline">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.5, new { @class = "control-label" })
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.5)
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've been using this layout before using Kendo, and it worked fine. In  a Kendo Window it causes 1-column layout. The only way I could make it work was by reducing second number.