# Rendering 2-column layout in an Editor Template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, twitter-bootstrap-3, mvc-editor-templates

I'd like to have a 2 column layout, but the problem is I can't place half my HTML codes inside `else` segment. Any Idea?

This is the editor template:

```
@{int i = 0;}
@foreach (var property in ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties)
{
    if (property.PropertyName.StartsWith("Z") ||
                property.IsReadOnly)
    {
        continue;
    }
    if (i++ % 2 == 0)
    {
        <div class="form-group form-inline col-xs-12">
            <div class="col-xs-5">
                @Html.Label(property.DisplayName, new { @for = property.PropertyName, @class = "control-label col-xs-3" })
                @Html.TextBox(property.PropertyName, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-5">
                @Html.Label(property.DisplayName, new { @for = property.PropertyName, @class = "control-label col-xs-3" })
                @Html.TextBox(property.PropertyName, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

The second `<div class="col-xs-5">` and the closing tags should be in else.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: a 2 column layout! :)

Comment: with 2 same columns? Or you want "ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties" to render odd left - even right?

Comment: odd left - even right. What do you call it!? :)

Comment: I'm trying to use `I` to achieve this and that's why I have the if anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need start a containing `<div>` and then in the `if` block, close and start a new containing `<div>`

```
@{int i = 0;}
<div class="form-group form-inline col-xs-12">
    @foreach (var property in ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties) {
        if (property.PropertyName.StartsWith("Z") || property.IsReadOnly) {
            continue;
        }
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            @Html.Label(property.DisplayName, new { @for = property.PropertyName, @class = "control-label col-xs-3" })
            @Html.TextBox(property.PropertyName, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
        if (++i % 2 == 0) {
            @:</div><div class="form-group form-inline col-xs-12">
        }
    }
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what exactly you want in the else, but to have but you should declare the parent div before you loop through the other objects.  Also if its a two column, they should be `col-xs-6` as explained on [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html).

```
 @{int i = 0;}
<div class="form-group form-inline">
<div class="row">
    @foreach (var property in ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties)
    {
        if (property.PropertyName.StartsWith("Z") ||
                    property.IsReadOnly)
        {
            continue;
        }
        if (i++ % 2 == 0)
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                    @Html.Label(property.DisplayName, new { @for = property.PropertyName, @class = "control-label col-xs-3" })
                    @Html.TextBox(property.PropertyName, new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
        }
        else
        {
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                  @Html.Label(property.DisplayName, new { @for = property.PropertyName, @class = "control-label col-xs-3" })
                  @Html.TextBox(property.PropertyName, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        }
    }
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I want to have odd properties in one column and even ones in another. And that's why I'm using the `I`. And about `col-xs-6`, if I use it all of the elements will be under each other, and that's in fact another [problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30296417/).

Comment: You say you want odd properties on one side and even the other column, are these always in pairs (so do they belong on the same row) or will one column be empty? If that makes sense.

Comment: it's possible. I have many classes and some of them might be odd.

Answer (score 1):

I think they way you are trying to render your form is way too complicated for no reason, col-xs-** already floats left, you do not have to worry about "odd left - even right".

```
<div class="row form-horizontal">
@foreach (var property in ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties)
{
    if (property.PropertyName.StartsWith("Z") || property.IsReadOnly)
    {
        continue;
    }
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="form-group">
             @Html.Label(property.DisplayName, new { @for = property.PropertyName, @class = "control-label col-xs-12 col-sm-3" })
             <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
                  @Html.TextBox(property.PropertyName, new { @class = "form-control" })
             </div>            
        </div>
    </div>
}
</div>
```